# How to get AngularJS Directive name from inside Controller Code?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have 2 AngularJS Directives which are very similar, so i want to use one single controller to handle both of them.
In order to differentiate in the Controller code between the 2 directives, I want to be able to know which directive is currently being used. Is there a way i can tell? it sounds like a trivial function in AngularJS, but i can't find it in the docs so far.

```
<div dirA ></div>
<div dirB'></div>

app.directive('dirA', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        controller: 'CommonCtrl',
    };
});

app.directive('dirB', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        controller: 'CommonCtrl',
    };
});

app.controller('CommonCtrl',
    function CommonCtrl($scope, $location, $log, $attrs) {
      // how do i know which directive is using me now???
    }
);
```

Comment: If you need to know which directive is using it, can you really say that the controller is common between the two?

Comment: I was going to ask the same :)

Comment: write two controllers and isolate their common functionality into a function.

Comment: I've added an answer that will work for you, but I think the suggestion at the end of my answer is probably your best bet. I can add some code to show that if you like.

Comment: @Fourth the language probably failed me here :) there is very little deviation in functionality between DirA and DirB. When i said common, i meant there is common functionality between the 2 and i need to branch the logic in some statements based on the directive name, or if you can help with a better practice in AngularJS?

Comment: @akonsu where should i put the function? as it should be accessing other AngularJS services, etc... ?

Comment: I've created a pull request for this: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/8839 If somebody really needs it, try convincing the Angular team to merge it by providing your example where this feature would make things significantly better.

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can just set a property on the directive's controller, which is automatically injected to your linking function if specified:

[Here's a plunk for it](http://plnkr.co/edit/lN7xKTkUyAC9jgcvIVkP?p=preview)

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.directive('dirA', function (){
  return {
    controller: 'CommonCtrl',
    scope: true,
    template: '<button ng-click="test()">Test A</button>',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
      ctrl.directiveName = 'dirA';
    }
  };
});

app.directive('dirB', function (){
  return {
    controller: 'CommonCtrl',
    scope: true,
    template: '<button ng-click="test()">Test B</button>',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
      ctrl.directiveName = 'dirB';
    }
  };
});

app.controller('CommonCtrl', function ($scope, $window){
  var ctrl = this;
  
  $scope.foo = 'bar';
  
  $scope.test = function (){
    $window.alert('Directive name is: ' + ctrl.directiveName);
  };
});
```

### This is probably not a good idea, though.

#### Coupling Warning!

This is going to lead to slightly tighter coupling in your app. Because now you have a dependency between your Controller which is supposed to encapsulate logic that manipulates your $scope (model), and your View because now your controller has a reference to a directive name or directive-specific data at least. This is going to hurt testability and possibly readability in the long run.

#### Suggestion: Use Inheritence

If the case is that you have slightly different functionality from different directives, it's probably better practice to create a CommonCtrl, then create a DirACtrl and DirBCtrl that prototypically inherit from CommonCtrl... if that makes sense.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i was using something similar already putting the directive as an attribute, so i can check for $attrs.dirA exists.I thought there is an easier way to do it natively. As for inheritance suggestion, i will try that again, but i didn't feel that i can separate the common code without duplicating the whole function, this is why i was looking for easier way to branch from a couple of statements in the code. i wish to vote up this answer, but this is my first question and apparently i still need more reputation to vote up, which i will get and i appreciate your help :)